# Django updating static files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, caching, server, browser-cache

Consider a scenario where my I have my website on a server.
All the static files will be cached when the user request for the first time and I push some changes in static file and I need a method so that when users request for the next time after changing the static files new files should be cached for one time

What is CachedStaticFilesStorage? Does this help in this case

---

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CachedFilesStorage is not recommended. 
Read the docs: [CachedFileStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage)

In your case I would use: [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) which uses a MD5 Hasher and place a Hash between your filename and suffix. So everytime you will deploy your application it will create a new hash. Browsers cache files by filenames therefore **in conclusion the browsers will be forced to download the updated files.**

Comment: Thank you,This helped me

Comment: Please mark the answer as the answer for your question by checking the tick